# Get parameters from URL Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, parameter

Assume I have a URL like this,

http://mystore.com/cms/sales/order/view/order_id/286/

I want to get values of the order_id which is 286,

Please help with some example or snippet in Magento 2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**By ObjectManager:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
echo $param = $request->getParam('order_id');
```

**By Factory Method**

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ...
) {
   $this->request = $request;
}

$this->request->getParam('order_id');
```

Note: Do not use objectManager directly in files as Magento 2 coding standards.

Comment: The ObjectManager way worked for me, I was trying to inject from Magento\Backend\App\Action, but injection didn't work so I tried the ObjectManager method, it works, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to inject `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` at `_construct`function then using

```
protected $request;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        ....//rest of parameters here
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
       ...//rest of constructor here
    }
    public function getIddata()
    {
    // use 
    $this->request->getParams(); // all params
        return $this->request->getParam('order_id');
    }
```

At BLock class, you don't need to inject this class. Use

`$this->getRequest()` instead of `$this->request`.

Comment: can we use same code in block files?

Answer (score 3):

**=> Factory Method :**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Something;
class ClassName 
{
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        ....//rest of parameters here
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
       ...//rest of constructor here
    }
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->request->getParam("order_id");
    }
}
```

**=> Object Manager :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
echo $request->getParam('order_id');
```

**=> Note :** Do not use direct object manager as magento coding format

Answer (score 2):

In a controller which extends **Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action** you can get the request with **$this->getRequest()->getPost()**.

In a custom class, you need to inject the request in the constructor in below way:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        ....//rest of parameters here
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
       ...//rest of constructor here
    }
```

Then you can get the values like below:

```
public function getPost()
{
    return $this->request->getParam("order_id");
}
```